# Loop through javascript object without knowing names of items

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I want to loop through a javascript object passed in like this:

```
{familyid:434832,groupid:5332,programtypecode:'daycare'}
```

But I don't know the parameter names.  There could be any number of parameters with various different names.  I want to get the names of the parameters passed in, and of course also their values.  How do I get that?

Comment: `Object.keys(), Object.values(), Object.entries()` didn't worked for you ?

Comment: Thank you for the link to the other question.  That's where I found my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
const o = {
  familyid: 434832,
  groupid: 5332,
  programtypecode: 'daycare'
}

keys = Object.keys(o)

// Do something with your keys, like
for (key of keys) {
 console.log(`${key} => ${o[key]}`)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result in form of array of array of arrays then use `Object.entries`

```js
let obj = {familyid:434832,groupid:5332,programtypecode:'daycare'}
console.log(Object.entries(obj))
```

If you want to directly loop then use `for..in`

```js
let obj = {familyid:434832,groupid:5332,programtypecode:'daycare'}

for(let k in obj){
  console.log(`${k}:${obj[k]}`)
}
```

Comment: This is a superior answer, but I'll leave mine anyway. I always forget about the entries tuple-ifier...